# Buy X and another Product Y free

Tags: magento2, discount, coupon

Although I am familiar with Magento1, I am relatively new to Magento2. I need add functionality where a customer buy X product and get different Y product as free. I am overriding the Buy X and get Y free action. I am not able to achieve it. I would appreciate  if anyone provide inputs on where to started for this issue.

Below is the code which is not working-

> module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/Action/Discount/BuyXGetY.php

```
 public function calculate($rule, $item, $qty)
    {
<snip>
    if($rule->getSimpleAction()=='buy_x_get_y' && ($item->getSku())=='24-UG06'){
                $cart->addProduct('24-UG07','1')->save();
<snip>
            }
```

I am aware that it is not the best practice to edit core files. I am just playing around the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an observer or plugin for this purpose. Here is the method to achieve this through an observer.

In your `events.xml`

```
<event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="freeproduct" instance="CompanyName\ModuleName\Observer\FileName" />
</event>
```

**Observer File**

```
<?php
    namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

    class FileName implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
            $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
            $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
            $price = 0; //set your price here
            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: how can we do this using a plugin?